# How to access In XCUITestCase UITableViewRowAction and How to take action from XCUITestCase Leftswape delete tableViewCell

Tags: swift

Basically I want to access the UItableViewRowAction event in XCUITestCase. But I couldn't find any solution for this.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe you can elaborate it a little. Anyway: A `XCUIElement` has functions like `swipeLeft()` etc. that trigger a `UItableViewRowAction`, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement). Did you look for this?

Comment: The swipe left is fine. How to take action on the delete button

Comment: let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, indexPath) in
            self.presenter.list[indexPath.row].isSelected = true
             self.deleteVideoVideoWarningController()
           /* var eventList = self.presenter.parkedInfo.eventList
            eventList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.presenter.parkedInfo.eventList = eventList
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) */
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table view with cells that can be swiped left, and that swiping shows a delete button entitled DELETE.
Then you could do the following:

```
let firstCell = XCUIApplication().cells.element(boundBy: 0)
firstCell().swipeLeft()
let deleteButton = firstCell.buttons[„DELETE“]
deleteButton.tap()
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your edit! Your delete button does not have any title text. Thus, you cannot access the button with `firstCell.buttons[„DELETE“]`.
From your screen shot it looks as if the delete button was the only button in the cell. If so, you could try `firstCell.buttons.firstMatch`.
If you have more buttons, you could access the delete button using `firstCell.buttons.element(boundBy: 0)` where „0“ had to be replaced by the correct index.

Comment: I tried this. But It not working. We don't have a button on the cell. UItableViewRowAction.